# Insert data with Vietnamese characters into a Firebird database

Tags: sql, character-encoding, firebird

Insert new records with Unicode data types into Firebird

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPERMISSOON
(
    NAME VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS
);

INSERT INTO TBLPERMISSOON (NAME)
VALUES ('Chạy ngay đi');
```

I want to add data with Vietnamese characters, how do I do it? It doesn't work right now and I don't know how to do it yet?

In SQL Server, I write it like this:

```
INSERT INTO TBLPERMISSOON (NAME) 
VALUES (N'Chạy ngay đi');
```

Comment: I have provided a generic answer, but if you are currently having problems, it is better to explicitly describe your problem using a [mre] that includes all relevant details like application used, connection configuration, and expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect using connection character set `UNICODE_FSS` or `UTF8` and - obviously - your application needs to have UTF-8 support. With those two you should be able to insert with the statement from your question:

```sql
INSERT INTO TBLPERMISSOON (NAME)
VALUES ('Chạy ngay đi');
```

Be aware that `UNICODE_FSS` is a reduced UTF-8 character set, it might be better to use `UTF8` instead.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much ..HIHI !!